# Updating users password Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me why I'm getting error flash message when I'm trying to update user password ? Here's the form:

```
        {!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'class' => 'bootstrap-wrapper', 'action' => ['UserController@passwordUpdate', $user->id]]) !!}
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('passwordOld', 'Įrašykite dabartinį slaptažodį') !!}
            {!! Form::password('passwordOld', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('password', 'Įrašykite naują slaptažodį') !!}
            {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <br>{!! Form::submit('Išsaugoti', ['class' => 'form-control btn btn-success',
            'style' => 'height: 45px']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And here's the function:

```
public function passwordUpdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    $passwordOld = Hash::make($request->passwordOld);

    if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id && $passwordOld == $user->password){
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();
        flash()->success('Slaptažodis sėkmingai pakeistas.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    else {
        flash()->error('Jūs neturite teisių.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

What causes that I'm getting `else` statement executed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing the old password and then comparing the string values is not going to work as expected since you will get a different hash each time.

so instead of:

```
Hash::make($request->passwordOld);
```

do:

```
Hash::check($request->passwordOld, Auth::user()->password);
```